# $|x|=7$,$|y|=3$ then $|\langle x,y \rangle |=21$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

Let $|G|=168$. Let $x,y \in G$ with $|x|=7$, $|y|=3$. Show that if  $yxy^{-1}=x^2$ then $|\langle x,y \rangle |=21$.

What I have done so far: since $\langle x \rangle \leq \langle x,y \rangle $ and $\langle y \rangle \leq \langle x,y \rangle $ then $7$ and $3$ divide $|\langle x,y \rangle |$, and $21 \leq |\langle x,y \rangle |$. Now, $|\langle x,y \rangle |$ must divide $168$ and is a multiple of $21$ so it is either $21$ or $84$. I am not sure how to use   $x^{-1}yx=y^2$ to conclude that it is of order $21$. Any hints appreciated.

Comment: The conditions $|x|=7$, $|y|=3$, $x^{-1}yx=x^2$ are not possible in any group. Did you mean $y^{-1}xy = x^2$?

Comment: I meant $xyx^{-1}=y^2$, sorry!

Comment: But $xyx^{-1} = y^2$ is what you wrote, and that is impossible.

Comment: Ah, yes I messed up again. It is like you said. I forgot that $x$ was of order $7$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write $yx=x^2y$, so that the group $H=\langle x,y\rangle$ can be written as
$$
H=\{x^iy^j\mid 0\le i\le 7, 0\le j\le 2\}.
$$
So we have $|H|=21$.

Comment: So, this means that all elements in $H$ are of the form $x^iy^j$ and so they are all distinct?

Comment: Yes, they are distinct. You have also argued that its order is at least $21$, so they must be distinct in your proof, too.

Comment: Yes thanks! Please note I made a mistake so $yx=x^2y$ in this case.

Comment: No problem, we can adapt the argument.